# Sum of multiple die

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Is there an efficient way of calculating the sum of multiple die $\ge x$? For example, if we rolled $12$ fair $6$-sided die, what is the probability the sum is at least $45$?

My only approach as of now is using central limit theorem to approximate this however, I am not sure if a number like $12$ is large enough.

Comment: For small numbers, recursive means are good (having solved it for $N-1$ dice, you just consider the $6$ possible cases for the $N^{th}$).  Beyond that, I'd use a normal approximation, as you propose.

Comment: Using recursive methods as @lulu suggests, 64-bit integers can directly handle all sums for up to 24 dice. The processing time required is on the order of a few microseconds. Double-precision  floating-point arithmetic can handle nearly 400 dice in a few milliseconds, with results that are likely more accurate than you would ever need.

Comment: With regard to the use of a normal approximation based on the Central Limit Theorem, you might take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4623008/probability-for-total-score-after-rolling-a-die-n-times/4623656#4623656

Answer (score 1):

If you want an exact computation, can use generating functions like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1646360/305862).

In our case, you have to expand :

$$\left(\frac16(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)\right)^{12}\tag{1}$$

$$=\frac{1}{6^{12}}\left(x^{12}+12x^{13}+ \cdots +12x^{71}+ x^{72}\right)^{12}$$

and sum the coefficients that are $\ge 45$, a task that must be done with a computer.

I have done it and I find this sum equal to :

$$P(S \ge 45)=\frac{735884981}{6^{12}}\approx 0.3381$$

(Thanks to Daniel Mathias who spotted an error, now corrected).

Here is the Matlab program I have written for this purpose ; please note the use of the convolution operation :

```
 n=12; % number of throws
 t=45; % threshold
 C=[1]; % initialisation of the list of coeff.
 U=[0,ones(1,6)]; % list of coeff. of x+x^2+...+x^6
 for k=1:n;
    C=conv(C,U); % convolution
 end;
 sum(C((t+1):end))/6^(n)
```

Comment: The normal approximation with continuity correction would be about $0.3363$ using `1-pnorm(44.5,42,sqrt(35))` in R.  So quite close with an absolute error of about $0.0018$.  The largest absolute error with $12$ dice is about $0.0022$, worst when you are looking at at least $38$ or $47$

Comment: @Henry How does it compare with 24 dice? $P(S>=90)\approx 0.2565504665$

Comment: @Daniel Mathias : No comparison possible, because there is no reason that there is linearity.

Comment: I meant to compare the result from normal approximation applied to 24 dice, how good is such approximation then?

Comment: @DanielMathias `1-pnorm(90-0.5,24*3.5,sqrt(24*35/12))` gives `0.2554697` so an absolute error of about $0.0011$, very close to the worst absolute error with $24$ dice when you are looking at at least $78$ or $91$

Comment: Any comment ?...